# PowerShell Invoke-Command fails to load dll

Tags: invoke-command

I saw other posts but none that helped me. Please help.

I ran the following cmdlet from my local Win7 desktop having PowerShell4 on it.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER123 -ScriptBlock {
Import-Module '\\mycomany.com\PS\Task.SQL.psd1'}
```

I got this error:

```
The specified module '\\mycomany.com\PS\Task.SQL.psd1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (\\mycomany.com...S\Task.SQL.psd1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
    + PSComputerName        : COMPUTER123
```

My setup is as follows:

The remote computer COMPUTER123 and my desktop are in same AD domain.

The command was issued from my Win7 computer under my account mycomany\Sam. This account is also a local admin on remote COMPUTER123 .

The PowerShell config file on COMPUTER123 does have this entry under CONFIGURATION to allow loading assemblies from NAS.

```
<runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
</runtime >
```

RDPing to COMPUTER123 and invoking following PowerShell command locally on it runs without any error.

```
Import-Module '\\\mycomany.com\PS\Task.SQL.psd1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Some research leads me to believe this is a double-hop issue. Solution is to use CREDSSP as shown here.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-second-hop-functionality-with-credssp/

Assuming this is the only solution so far, I wonder if there is a way to run the following command on every server computer in AD domain using GPO.

```
Enable-WSMaCredSSP -Role Server –Force
```

Otherwise, will I have to manually RDP onto every server computer I'm interested in and run above command?